# mix random with two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The concept is very simple, but I need help because cannot make this work.

I have 2 tables

```
name   last       hours
Mario  Rossi      8
Mario  Bianchi    8
Mario  Galli      4
Luigi  Masso      4
```

and the times

```
in      out               tot
08.00   16.00             8
09.00   17.00             8
10.00   18.00             8
11.00   19.00             8
08.00   12.00             4
09.00   13.00             4
10.00   14.00             4
11.00   15.00             4
```

I want this output:

```
Mario Rossi: random in/random out    
Mario Bianchi: random in/random out 
Mario Galli: random in/random out
Luigi Masso: random in/random out
```

in the range of the join   hours=tot tables

Comment: The link is `hours=tot` @M.chaudhry

Comment: i have tried to construct an array and to randomize it, but array_rand() mix the keys, and i have tryed with RAND() in mysql to limit the join but i  can't resolve it

Comment: i didn't know sql fiddle..it's very cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method that selects an appropriate random `in` time and then calculates the `out` time:

```
select t1.name, t1.last,
       (select in
        from table2 t2
        where t2.tot = t1.hours
        order by rand()
        limit 1
      ) as randomIn,
      addtime(randomin, t1.hours) as randomOut
from table1 t1;
```

Comment: thank you but don't work...phpmyadmin return an sql error syntax.. but i think is my mistake..

Comment: i have tryed another time but i think is a problem with addtime

Comment: ok i have solved changing type of the record from vharchar to time aaand it'a all... thank you